# Scrapy item import error: No module found

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm new to Scrapy and to python and when I try to import a class from items.py in VS Code I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'scraper.items'; 'scraper' is not a package
```

My folder structure:
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rjlk.png)

Tutorial I was trying to follow:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyE4oDxScfE

**scraper.py** code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scraper.items import ScraperItem

class ScrapySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scraper'

def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request('https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/c/639/bourbon-whiskey')
    
def parse(self, response):
    Item = ScraperItem()
    products = response.css('li.product-grid__item')
    
    for item in products:
        
            Item['name'] = item.css('p.product-card__name::text').get().strip(),
            Item['price'] = item.css('p.product-card__price::text').get().strip().replace('£', ''),
            Item['perL'] = item.css('p.product-card__unit-price::text').get().strip().replace('per litre', 'per L').replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
            
            yield item
        
    for x in range(2, 7):
        yield(scrapy.Request(f'https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/c/639/bourbon-whiskey?pg={x}', callback=self.parse))

process = CrawlerProcess(settings = {
    'FEED_URI': 'whiskey.csv',
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'
})

process.crawl(ScrapySpider)
process.start()
```

**items.py** code:

```
import scrapy


class ScraperItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    perL = scrapy.Field()
```

When I use:

```
..items import ScraperItem
```

I get the same error

Comment: probably because you are executing the script from outside of the project directory.  move your terminal current working directory inside the scraper folder

Answer (score 0):

the import needs to be relative to the execution directory. My guess is
scraper.scraper.item will work.